Can USB SuperDrive work with newer Macbook Pro/Air series?
I recently came across this beautiful looking device called USB SuperDrive while buying something on an e-commerce website.
After I searched about this device, I got to know that it's a portable USB CD/DVD-RW drive from the year 2008 which can burn & play CDs and DVDs.
I got interested to buy it. But I see this product being discontinued by Apple officially.
Will it work with the newer Macbook Pro/Air series with M1/M2/Intel processors?

You’ll need a usb-a to usb c adapter but SteveM is correct. Apple discontinued the drive but they are still supported. Heck I have a usb floppy drive that still works on my M1…

@SteveChambers Fascinating! Good to know that people still uses floppy drives and it works with newer devices as well.

@SteveChambers Can you add your thoughts as answer? I would like to upvote and know your experience.

@SteveChambers I haven’t even seen floppy disks for ages now. Wow.


Will it work with the newer Macbook Pro/Air series with M1/M2/Intel processors?

Yes. I am currently using it with my M1 Mac Studio, and I previously used it with a 2018 Intel Mac mini.
